# android Show Images of size less than 1mb

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

Hi this is the query I use to view images from selected folder. Now I still want to view images only less than 1Mb is it possible. I think its possible using 
**MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE** inside the code

```
String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
imagecursor=managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[] {"%/"+foldername+"/%"},null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like below. it will give you no. of image less than 1 MB.

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE
                         };
Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE + " < ? ",
                        new String[] {"1024"},null);
```

Comment: Hi thanx its working but now I cant able to open the folder. I want to open folder with image size less than 1Mb. My above code opens folder and your code works with size now how to combine both @Segi

Comment: Hi in the above code is it possible to view PDF also

Comment: no..its not possible..because pdf files are not consider under media.

Comment: Now is there any other method to see both Image and PDF known to you

Comment: yes, you can use other coder for get all pdf files.